# Audio recording won't work after incoming call

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am trying to record voice from microphone and later play it over speaker.  I use this code to accomplish it

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

It works fine, but if incoming call received (when app is active), after call is finished and app is resumed, microphone input not detected anymore.

I tried to handle  `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`  and reset AVAudioSession, but it won't work. Might I need to pause AVAudioRecorder when app is inactive, and record when it becomes active?

Am I doing something wrong, or it's iOS bug? I'm running on iOS 7. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you need to pause the `AVAudioRecorder` once a call is received and then resume it once it is ended. However, you don't do that in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, instead you need to implement `AVAudioSession`'s delegates, and more specifically `audioRecorderBeginInterruption:` and `audioRecorderEndInterruption:`.
Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW30) for an example of how to implement these delegates.
I would also look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706064/how-to-resume-recording-after-interruption-occured-in-iphone) which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW1) is the document about how to hand AudioSession interruption.

```
OSStatus error = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListener, NULL);

#pragma mark AudioSession listeners
void interruptionListener(  void *  inClientData,
                          UInt32    inInterruptionState)
{
    if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption)
    {
          //handle begin interruption
    }
    else if(inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption){
          //handle end  interruption
    }
}
```